# ReactJS and inheritance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to implement a remove function to hierarchical components. With it being app.jsx > notes.jsx > note.jsx. And this is just making a simple to-do list that im following from a tutorial. I've loaded it with babel and have a hard time understanding why this deletes the whole todo list rather than just a single list element.

App.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from './Note';
import Notes from './Notes';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notes: [{
        task: 'Learn webpacks'
      }, {
        task: 'Learn React'
      }, {
        task: 'Do laundry'
      }]
    };
  }


    render() {
        var notes = this.state.notes;
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick= {()=>this.addItem()}> + </button>
            <Notes items = {notes}
            onEdit = {(i, task) => this.itemEdited(i, task)} 
            removeItem = {(i) => this.removeItem(i)} 
             />

            </div>
            );  
    }

    itemEdited(i, task) {
    var notes = this.state.notes;

    if(task) {
      notes[i].task = task;
    }
    else {
      notes = notes.slice(0, i).concat(notes.slice(i + 1));
    }

    this.setState({
      notes: notes
    });
  }


    addItem() {
        this.setState({
        notes : this.state.notes.concat([{
            task : 'New Task'
        }])

        });
    }

    removeItem(i) {
    var notes = this.state.notes;
    this.setState({
        notes : this.state.notes.slice(0, i)
    });
    }
}
```

Notes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from './Note';

export default class Notes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var notes = this.props.items;

        return(
        <ul className='notes'>{notes.map((note, i) =>
            <li className = 'note' key = {'note' + i}>
                <Note value = {note.task}
                 onEdit = {this.props.onEdit.bind(null, i)}
                 removeItem = {this.props.removeItem.bind(null, i)}
                 /> 


            </li>
            )}</ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Note.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Note extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        edited: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {value, onEdit, ...props} = this.props;
        var edited = this.state.edited;

            return (
                <div {...props}> {
                    edited
                    ? <input type = 'text'
                      defaultValue = {value}
                      onBlur = {(e) => this.finishEdit(e)}
                      onKeyPress={(e) => this.checkEnter(e)}/>
                    : <div onClick={() => this.edit()}> {value} </div>
                }
                <button onClick = {(i) => this.props.removeItem(i
            )}>-</button>  
                </div>

            );
        }

        edit() {
        this.setState({edited: true});
        }

        checkEnter(e) {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
          this.finishEdit(e);
            }
        }

        finishEdit(e) {
        this.props.onEdit(e.target.value);
        this.setState({edited:false});
        }



}
```

Everything works fine but removing a single list element, instead of deleting the element it deletes the whole list. I think it has to do with the logic of passing down removeItem, but I don't know exactly what has to be passed down. The way I see it, note is the individual note/list element so in order to remove it the function would have to trickle down this class correct?

Edited: with attempt of how i think it should work.

Comment: `this.props.removeItem.bind(i)` is missing a `null` - you are binding to the index and therefor not passing in anything as an argument which causes the slice to go to the end.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the heads up, I found the problem and your comment lead me back to the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What had went wrong was 
1: was not binding null to `this.props.removeItem.bind(i)`

Secondly I was slicing the whole thing when what I intended to do was splice it, instead I just did it like this:

```
removeItem(i) {
    var notes = this.state.notes;
    notes = notes.slice(0, i).concat(notes.slice(i + 1));
    this.setState({
        notes : notes
    });
    }
```

take all the elements before that list and concatenate it with everything after. Although notes = notes.splice(i, 1) should also work correct? I tried it, but it would remove everything but that element.

Comment: if you don't mind using tools like underscore / lodash, you can do something like this:

notes = _.without(notes, _.findWhere(notes, {id: 1}));